# Windows Phone - Activate/Execute app based off of conditions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to write a Windows Phone app that executes and runs code based off of certain phone conditions.  Similarly to how the If this then that(IFTTT) app works on Android/iOS, I'd like to perform an action when certain conditions are met.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any example or documentation on something like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8.1 supports triggering background tasks based on certain conditions. If the conditions you're interested are included in the supported triggers then you'll be able to use this approach.

More documentation at:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh977056(v=win.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh977056%28v=win.10%29.aspx) and   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977058.aspx

An example at http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/23/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-multitasking-and-background-tasks/

and more information from this //Build/ talk: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-518